# data-content for multiple URL's when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a javascript and jquery for which I need your help:

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $( '.website' ).popover(
        {
            'trigger'   : 'hover',
            'placement' : 'right'
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-content="http://www.google.com,http://www.yahoo.com" class="website" >Google Website</a>
```

When I hover on the "Google Website", it shows both the URLs. For the same data-content, when clicked on any URL, it should redirect to respective page.

The below code will do for 1 URL. But how to view 2 different URL's in 2 different tabs:

```
$('.website').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 window.open($(e.target).attr('data-content'), '_blank')
})
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your URLs are comma-separated in the `data-content` attribute. In that case:

```
$('.website').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).attr('data-content').split(',').forEach(function(url) {
        window.open(url, '_blank');
   });
});
```

This will not work if any of your URLs has an actual comma in it. Also, **this could cause serious accessibility issues** so I would suggest that you rethink whatever you are doing.

Comment: I mean, sometimes I want to open www.google.com or sometimes www.yahoo.com. Now only google.com opens when I click on "Google Website".

Comment: How do you determine when to open Google and when to open Yahoo?

Comment: When clicked on Google Website, it should show me both the URLs. Then I can decide which one to open. Is that possible?

Comment: @user2201935 Yes it's possible to show both urls, but your code doesn't demonstrate any attempt to do this. I would use a jQuery dialog or something. Try it out and update your question with your attempt.

Comment: But I dont have any idea how to do that using jQuery. Is it possible to help please? please